# Unity Click on 1 object to trigger another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Please keep in mind that I'm new to Unity. I have 2 script that I want to "combline" but when I try then it don't Work.

I have a Script `(Name : RobotController)`. This script controls the movement of the player. Up/Jump, Down, Left and Right. (This Works with Keyboard keys only atm)

This script Works just fine but now I want to add the feature of touch keys for phone. With this I mean that if a person click on the "up-Arrow" the player shall jump.

The Up-Arrow is an object.

This is were I get my problem. I have created the Up-Arrow with a collider and a script.

Up-Arrow script:

```
public class NewJumpScript : MonoBehaviour {



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnMouseOver()
{
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))) 
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }
}
}
```

Here is the RobotController script´, with ground check and so on.

```
public class RobotController : MonoBehaviour {
//This will be our maximum speed as we will always be multiplying by 1
public float maxSpeed = 2f;
public GameObject player;
public GameObject sprite;
//a boolean value to represent whether we are facing left or not
bool facingLeft = true;
//a value to represent our Animator
Animator anim;
//to check ground and to have a jumpforce we can change in the editor
bool grounded = true;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundRadius = 1f;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public float jumpForce = 300f;
private bool isOnGround = false;
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        isOnGround = true;  
    }

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision) {
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    isOnGround = false;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    player = GameObject.Find("player");

    //set anim to our animator
    anim = GetComponent <Animator>();
}


void FixedUpdate () {
    //set our vSpeed
    //set our grounded bool

    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    //set ground in our Animator to match grounded
    anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

    float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");//Gives us of one if we are moving via the arrow keys
    //move our Players rigidbody
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);   
    //set our speed
    anim.SetFloat ("Speed",Mathf.Abs (move));
    //if we are moving left but not facing left flip, and vice versa
    if (move > 0 && !facingLeft) {

        Flip ();
    } else if (move < 0 && facingLeft) {
        Flip ();
    }

}

void Update(){
    if ((isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) || (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))) {
        anim.SetBool("Ground",false);
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
    }

    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 0.2f, 0.2f);
    }
    if (isOnGround == true && Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
    {
        gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    }
}


//flip if needed
void Flip(){
    facingLeft = !facingLeft;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
}
```

What needs to happen is that when The "Up-arrow" in the game is clicked then The person shall jump on the same tearms as in the RobotController script.
I hope you understand my question.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same answer to both of the questions, because they are so similar. You can easily modify the code to your needs.

This is only one way to do it. There are probably many more, but this is the best I have encountered so far.

On the QUI button, script like this is needed:

```
private Mover playerMover;
void Start()
{
    playerMover = GameObject.Find("Character").GetComponent<Mover>();
}
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        Debug.Log("pressed");
        playerMover.MoveButtonPressed();
    }
}
```

Notice that find is only done ones in start function, because it is computationally heavy.

And on the Character gameobject, script component like this is needed:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {
    public void MoveButtonPressed()
    {
        lastPressedTime = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }

    public double moveTime = 0.1;
    private double lastPressedTime = 0.0;
    void Update()
    {
        if(lastPressedTime + moveTime > Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)
        {
            // Character is moving
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        else
        {
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```